# If Exist inside of For loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, if-statement, nested

I am having trouble getting this code to work after modifying it to accept multiple arguments. I am getting "( was unexpected at this time." at the second for loop. (Line 23).

Any idea if it's even possible to have these if groups inside of a for loop? From what I've seen it is possible.

Instead of the if exist group. I could just use an IF NOT EXIST but I don't know how to make it to skip the rest of the code in the loop for the current item, but continue for the loop for the next item. I'm unable to find how to do this, and only found how to exit the loop entirely which I don't want to do.

```
@echo off
:variables
set script_dir="E:\Plex Scripts\DVR"
set script1=MCEBuddyScriptv2.bat
set method2=GPU
set script2=ScanMedia%method2%.ps1
set extension=mkv
set logfile=post_processing_log.txt
set history=history.txt
:change_directory
cd /d %script_dir%
:method
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:counter
set argCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
    set /A argCount+=1
    set "argVec[!argCount!]=%%~x"
)
::How many videos we will attempt to process
echo Number of files to process: %argCount%
:loop_start
for /L %%i in (1,1,%argCount%) do (
    set fullpath=!argVec[%%i]!
    ::get new filepath (with new extension)
    REM :names
    for %%f in (!fullpath!) do set itemname=%%~nf
    for %%f in (!fullpath!) do set newpath=%%~dpnf.%extension%
    ::if logfile doesn't exist then create it
    REM :log_init
    if not exist %logfile% echo This log file is a detailed history of the DVR Post Process scipt. >> %logfile%
    if not exist %history% echo This is a history of the items processed with the DVR Post Process script. >> %history%
    ::check if input file exist
    REM :check
    if exist ( !fullpath! ) (
        REM :script1
        set state=Processing started
        echo %date% - %time% - !state! for !itemname! with %script1% >> %logfile%
        call %script1% !fullpath!
        set state=Processing finished
        echo %date% - %time% - !state! for !itemname! with %script1% >> %logfile%
        REM :script2
        set state=Processing started
        echo %date% - %time% - !state! for !itemname! with %script2% >> %logfile%
        powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %script2% -Path "!newpath!" -LimitCPU -AutoRepair -RemoveOriginal -RemoveRepaired -IAcceptResponsibility
        set state=Processing finished
        echo %date% - %time% - !state! for !itemname! with %script2% >> %logfile%
        REM :log_final
        echo %date% - %time% - Plex post processing script finished for !itemname!. The file will be moved and added to the library. >> %logfile%
        echo. >> %logfile%
        REM :history_final
        echo %date% - %time% - !itemname! >> %history%
    ) else (
        echo %date% - %time% - !itemname! does not exist. Error code 1. >> %logfile%
    )
)
:end
exit /b 0
```

Edit: Got it to work by removing the parenthesis from the "if exist ( !fullpath! ) ..."

I'm not sure why that even worked initially, before putting inside the for loop. Anyway here is the final code.

```
@echo off

:variables
set script_dir="E:\Plex Scripts\DVR"
set script1=MCEBuddyScriptv2.bat
set method2=GPU
set script2=ScanMedia%method2%.ps1
set extension=mkv
set logfile=post_processing_log.txt
set history=history.txt

:change_directory
cd /d %script_dir%

:method
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:counter
set argCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
    set /A argCount+=1
    set "argVec[!argCount!]=%%~x"
)
::How many videos we will attempt to process
echo Number of files to process: %argCount%

:loop_start
for /L %%i in (1,1,%argCount%) do (
    set fullpath="!argVec[%%i]!"
    echo !fullpath!

    ::get new filepath (with new extension)
    :names
    for %%f in (!fullpath!) do set itemname=%%~nf
    echo !itemname!
    for %%f in (!fullpath!) do set newpath=%%~dpnf.%extension%
    echo !newpath!

    ::if logfile doesn't exist then create it
    :log_init
    if not exist %logfile% echo This log file is a detailed history of the DVR Post Process scipt. >> %logfile%
    if not exist %history% echo This is a history of the items processed with the DVR Post Process script. >> %history%

    ::check if input file exist
    :check
    if exist !fullpath! (
        :script1
        set state=Processing started
        echo %date% - %time% - !state! for !itemname! with %script1% >> %logfile%
        call %script1% !fullpath!
        set state=Processing finished
        echo %date% - %time% - !state! for !itemname! with %script1% >> %logfile%

        :script2
        set state=Processing started
        echo %date% - %time% - !state! for !itemname! with %script2% >> %logfile%
        powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %script2% -Path "!newpath!" -LimitCPU -AutoRepair -RemoveOriginal -RemoveRepaired -IAcceptResponsibility
        set state=Processing finished
        echo %date% - %time% - !state! for !itemname! with %script2% >> %logfile%

        :log_final
        echo %date% - %time% - Plex post processing script finished for !itemname!. The file will be moved and added to the library. >> %logfile%
        echo. >> %logfile%

        :history_final
        echo %date% - %time% - !itemname! >> %history%
    ) else (
        echo %date% - %time% - !itemname! does not exist. Error code 1. >> %logfile%
    )
)
:end
exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if /?
```

> ```
> Performs conditional processing in batch programs.
>
> IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command
> IF [NOT] string1==string2 command
> IF [NOT] EXIST filename command
> ```

There are no parentheses around the `filename` token. Use

```
if exist !fullpath! (
```

or even

```
if exist "!fullpath!" (
```

Comment: You're right. Not sure why it was working before I put the if exist command inside of the for loop. Got it all working now.